# extracting values from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

Given a string of the form `"(a,{b:c,d:e,f:g},h})"`, I want to extract `a,c,e,g,h` from the string.
i.e. string will always contain 3 parameters, where 2nd parameter is of the form `{b:c,d:e,f:g}` i.e. it contains key value pairs and there can be any number of them. I want to extract all the values leaving behind keys.

Also I want to extract first and third parameter i.e. `a` and `h` in the above string.
I am trying to scan the string and extract on character by character bases but I am not able to do extract values from 2nd argument.

Is there any efficient method to do it may be using regular expressions ?

Comment: why have that string? is it intentionally malformed? can you do something about the formatting?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer yes it is intentionally stored as above format.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
\(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+),\{([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+):([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+),([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+):([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+),([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+):([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\},([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\}\)
```

The first group is `a`, second is `b`, etc:

```
> str.match(/\(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+),\{([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+):([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+),([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+):([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+),([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+):([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\},([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\}\)/)
["(a,{b:c,d:e,f:g},h})", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
```

Comment: Sorry for not making the question much clearer. a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h all are some strings in themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complicated solution using the versatile `split` function:

```
var str = "(a,{b:c,d:e,f:g},h)"
var outstr = "";

var parts = str.split(",");
for (var ixPart = 0; ixPart < parts.length; ++ixPart) {
    if (ixPart > 0) outstr += ",";
    var part = parts[ixPart];
    if (part.indexOf(":") > 0) {
        var parts2 = parts[ixPart].split(":");
        var part2 = parts2[1];
        if (part2.indexOf("}") >= 0)
           outstr += part2.substring(0, part2.indexOf("}"));
        else outstr += part2;
    } else {
       if (part.indexOf("(") == 0) outstr += part.substring(1);
       else if (part.indexOf(")") >= 0)
           outstr += part.substring(0, part.indexOf(")"));
       else outstr += part;
    }
}

return outstr;
```

Comment: BTW, I am assuming that the final } just before the final ) is a typo. That is, the } after the "h". If it isn't a typo, then my code needs further modification ...

Comment: I am pretty sure it will NOT work faster than regex processing. But it was kind of fun to write it.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var testString = "(a,{b:c,d:e,f:g},h)";

var parameterArray = testString.split(/\((.+?),\{.+?:(.+?),.+?:(.+?),.+?:(.+?)\},(.+?)\)/);
```

This assumes that the `})` at the end of the sample string is a type-o, but it's easy to modify if not.

Answer (score 0):

Divide and conquer!

```
function extract (str) {
  str = str.trim ().split (/\s*,\s*/); // split on , chars with optional surrounding spaces
  return str.map (function (v) { // create array from values
    // remove prefix and/or suffix from required values :
    // first ignore any leading ( or { chars
    // then ignore a single word followed by :
    // use the following trimmed string as the data
    // ignore any ) or } at the end  
    return (v.match (/^[({]*(?:\w\s*:\s*)?\s*(.*?)\s*[)}]*$/) || ['', v]) [1];
  });
}
```

This assumes that the data strings will never :

1. be blank
2. contain , characters
3. begin with ( or {
4. end with ) or }

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the string is known as you described, I would first edit the string to make it into JSON and then use `eval`

Example:

```
var str1 = "('word1',{b:'word2',d:'word3',f:'word4'},'word5')";

// Edit the string to JSON format by replacing '(' and ')' with '[' and ']'
var str2 = str1.replace(/\(/, '[').replace(/\)/, ']')

// str2 is now => "['word1',{b:'word2',d:'word3',f:'word4'},'word5']"

var obj = eval(str2);

// All you results are now in obj.

var result1 = obj[0]; // This gets'word1'

//Similarly you can get the rest as follows:
obj[1].b // This gives you 'word2'
obj[1].d // 'word3'
obj[1].f // 'word4'
obj[2]   // 'word5'
```

If `obj[1]` has a variable number of key/value pairs and you want only value you can iterate over the object `obj[1]` as follows:

```
for (var key in obj[1]) {
  obj[1][key];  // This gives the values in each iteration
}
```